# Eclipse Luna excessively slow

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

Kelper was significantly quicker at opening folders with lots of files in them (approx 200 files on average).  Luna on the other hand will spin for about 10 seconds to open each folder.  I have up heapsize and re clone my workspace as to not use any of my old eclipse properties.  I thought this fix the issue it has not.  Does anyone have any other ideas (min heap size 1024, max 2048), ram is not an issue or processing package?

Comment: Are these folders on a local disk?

Comment: They are local files for the most part *.xml files.

Comment: Sounds like a question for the [Eclipse User Forums](http://forums.eclipse.org/) IMHO...

Comment: I have observed this as well - I believe it is doing some more in-depth XML parsing, but I cannot confirm it.

Comment: What does the progress view show when opening a folder?

Comment: First it is the circle with 1/4 white/black eclipse loading mouse over.  Then it goes into the multi color spinning dial MacOS mouse over showing it not responding for a bet until all the files in the folder are loaded.

Answer (score 15):

To answer your non-question, yes, my Eclipse Luna is also extremely slow.

But that is probably due to the Scala plugin (I edit Scala sources). After typing every 3-5 letters, it locks up for 5 to 10 seconds "Updating occurrence annotations". It seems that the thread dependencies are wrong. The GUI editor locks up waiting for background analysis. The solution would be to switch off all kinds of context hints and code completion. I have not yet found a configuration that makes it useable.

### UPDATE:

Checking "Always run in background" and "Show heap status" in

Window > Preferences > General

drastically improved responsiveness (Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 with Scala IDE 4.0.0-M2).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  I already had heap status on to track that value but I didn't have always run in background.  Good to know I am not the only that thinks there was major performance degradation between luna and kepler.

Comment: Immediately fixed my problem. Thanks for that.